# variable relationships within a single query in neo4j

Tags: variables, neo4j, relationship

I am new to neo4j. I have two types of nodes in the database, i.e., "Person" and "House". I want to create relationships between each "Person" and the "House" with names like "resident_1", "resident_2", etc. Please find my code below:

```
CREATE (n1:Person {name: '1'})
CREATE (n2:Person {name: '2'})
CREATE (n3:Person {name: '3'})
CREATE (n4:Person {name: '4'})
CREATE (t1:House {name:"T1"})
With n1, n2,n3,n4,t1
MATCH(a:House{name: "T1"})
with a
MATCH(b:Person) 
WITH a, b
Create (a)-[r:resident_1]->(b)
RETURN type(r)
```

The output generates

```
╒════════════╕
│"type(r)"   │
╞════════════╡
│"resident_1"│
├────────────┤
│"resident_1"│
├────────────┤
│"resident_1"│
├────────────┤
│"resident_1"│
└────────────┘
```

But, I want to generate

```
╒════════════╕
│"type(r)"   │
╞════════════╡
│"resident_1"│
├────────────┤
│"resident_2"│
├────────────┤
│"resident_3"│
├────────────┤
│"resident_4"│
└────────────┘
```

How to do that? Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You cannot create dynamic relationship types in Neo4j, unless you install the apoc library. But more importantly, is there a reason why you would use different relationship types for different persons  ?

Comment: Thanks, @Graphileon, for your suggestion. I want to use these specifically named relationships as a marker for the later stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cypher only supports static value of relationship type so you need to use an APOC function (it is awesome) if the relationship type is dynamic.  If you need help on installing APOC, here it is: https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/installation/.
You need to create a map of Person (resident) to the Relationship Type (resident_1) then we will use apoc.create.relationship:

https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.create/apoc.create.relationship/

```
// Let us collect all person and order by name
MATCH (b:Person)
WITH collect(b) as setB, count(b) as cnt ORDER BY b.name
// create a map of person and relationship type (person1 -> resident_1)
WITH [idx in RANGE(1, cnt)| {b: setB[idx-1], rela: 'resident_' + toString(idx)}] as relTypes
// get the house node
MATCH (a:House{name: "T1"})
// relaTypes is a list so let us do UNWIND (this is like a for loop)
UNWIND relTypes as relType
// each relationship type is a dictionary so resident_1 is mapped to person1 and so on.  relType.rela is the relationship string that we want
CALL apoc.create.relationship(a, relType.rela, NULL, relType.b) YIELD rel
RETURN a.name as name, relType.b as person, relType.rela as relType
```

Below is the result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, @jose_bacoy, for your prompt reply. I have implemented your suggestion, but now it is displaying a new error as the following:                                                                                           
` In a WITH/RETURN with DISTINCT or an aggregation, it is not possible to access variables declared before the WITH/RETURN: b (line 9, column 51 (offset: 289))
"WITH collect(b) as setB, count(b) as cnt ORDER BY b.name"`.  Do you have any clue about it? 
                                                   ^